# Can any one suggest a script by which i can search a keyword in logs of six different unix servers

Tags: unix

i have six unix servers to search.. its a PITA to search all six servers manually every time i do a transaction. So can anyone suggest a script which can search a keyword in all the six servers, at once. Currently, i am using a combination of find and grep and manually login to different servers and search for the keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [PSSH](http://www.theether.org/pssh/docs/0.2.3/pssh-HOWTO.html), ex :

```
$ cat servers.txt
unix1
unix2
unix3

$ pssh -h servers.txt -o /tmp/output 'find / -name "foobar"'

$ ls /tmp/output
```

Combined with an `ssh-agent` to deal with key pairs, all becomes easy.